# error MSB3073: The command exited with code 3

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I try build the solution created in Visual Studio 2013 in Visual Studio 2015,

I got the follow error:

> "18>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1250,5):
>   error MSB3073: The command ""%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\microsoft
>   shared\TextTemplating\12.0\TextTransform.exe" -a !!build!true
>   "C:\Users\b3bi\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SKNL\trunk\GDP\My
>   Project\AssemblyInfo.tt"" exited with code 3."

The file in this error shows is:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEventDependsOn></PreBuildEventDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target
      Name="PreBuildEvent"
      Condition="'$(PreBuildEvent)'!=''"
      DependsOnTargets="$(PreBuildEventDependsOn)">

    **<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PreBuildEvent)" />**

  </Target>
```

Someone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The path is wrong.
In my case the WiX version was updated in the files. But I had not changed the name (the version number) in the code, thus leading to the path error - which is reffered to as "code 3".

The answer is therefore to edit the path in the pre-build event command line (Project Settings -> Pre-Build Event), so that it is correct.

[visual-studio-2013](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013) [visual-studio-2015](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Please let me know which file you are referring here when you said "edit the path in the code manually". I'm facing similar error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an example: I had "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\TextTemplating\11.0\TextTransform.exe" "$(ProjectDir)\ServerMetaBlock.tt" and it need to change to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\TextTemplating\14.0\TextTransform.exe" "$(ProjectDir)\ServerMetaBlock.tt" . Notice the 11.0 to 14.0

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error while build in azure pipeline, After installing the framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0', I was able to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

After installing vs 22 and un installing 2019 I faced this issue, I checked the runtimes and 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was missing
downloaded it from [here][1]
and everything worked fine.

plz note that the dll that was mentioned in the error, was targeting 3.0.1, you may need to install a different version according to the version u r targeting
[1]: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-3.1.416-windows-x64-installer

Answer (score -1):

it's decide my problem

dotnet tool install --global protobuf-net.Protogen --version 3.1.22

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33343980)